# How do I send some alert or msg to another php file

Tags: php, html, ajax

I have two php files...

PHP_File2 is a file which receives some data with post methods...and then it writes that data to some file and performs some operation

PHP_File1 is the file where I want to show the data in some input box or to some other text tags as soon as data is received to PHP_File2, without refreshing PHP_File1 or without reloading it...
[image]
So, how can I achieve this?

Comment: You can instead send the request to PHP_File1, and at the top of this file you can use php include() to include the execution of PHP_File2 before the PHP_File1. This way you can handle the data in PHP_File2 and then set the variables you want  to handle in PHP_File1

Comment: but how do I show data on PHPfile1 as soon as I received.

Comment: any variable available in FIle2 is also available in File1, that's how you pass the data between them to display  using File1